# Cadastral data of Spain and Italy

Tags: geospatial

I'm looking for cadastral geodata of Italy and Spain, especially for agricultural areas, countrywide. I found files for other European countries like the Czech Republic, Austria and France, but I can't find anything for Spain and Italy.

(For spain, I found a downloader for Qgis, but it contains every cadastral object, including buildings etc.).

It does not matter if these files are WFS oder Esrishapes.

Note: I don't speak Spanish or Italian.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in Spanish agricultural data, you have a bunch of information in SIGPAC viewer http://sigpac.mapa.es/fega/visor/
It is possible to download data in some regions of Spain. For example you can download data from Community of Navarre in the next link: http://sigpac.tracasa.es/descargas/

[image]

Just type the name of a town in the search bar ('buscar municipio'), for example `VILLAFRANCA` and click on `Información alfanumérica` to get a csv or `Información gráfica` to get a shp.
You can also download data from Castilla-La Mancha in this webpage (but you need to register). http://pagina.jccm.es/agricul/sigpac_datos/sigpac.php